# How to create an object that can be drawn on the method onDraw()?

Tags: java, android, android-canvas, ondraw

I am trying to create an object that can be called whenever I want to draw something on the onDraw() function of my class. Here is my code which is not working:

```
//object class
public class DrawObject extends Canvas {

Paint paint = new Paint();

public void setColor(int color){
    paint.setColor(color);
}
    // I want to draw an arrow to instead of a line 
public void drawArrow(float startPointX, float startPointY, float endPointX, float endPointY){
    drawLine(startPointX, startPointY, endPointX, endPointY, paint);
    // draw the rest of the arrow here
}
}
```

for the main class:

```
public class Screen extends ImageView{

Paint paint = new Paint();

public Screen(Context context){
    super(context);

    paint.setColor(Color.BLACK);
    paint.setStyle(Style.STROKE);
}

public void onDraw(DrawObject drawObject){
    //called DrawObject instead on Canvas

    drawObject.drawArrow(10,10,100,100);
            // I want to draw the arrow here but it is not working.
}
```

can someone please tell me what is the proper way to do it? Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Extending `Canvas` is the wrong approach since you get a canvas supplied by the system which you have to use. You can't force Android to use your subclass of `Canvas`. Instead you can simply pass the `Canvas` to your class whenever it needs it.

```
public class DrawObject {

    Paint paint = new Paint();

    public void setColor(int color) {
        paint.setColor(color);
    }

    // I want to draw an arrow to instead of a line
    public void drawArrow(Canvas canvas, float startPointX, float startPointY, float endPointX, float endPointY) {
        canvas.drawLine(startPointX, startPointY, endPointX, endPointY, paint);
        // draw the rest of the arrow here
    }
}
```

And use like

```
public void onDraw(Canvas canvas){
    drawObject.drawArrow(canvas, 10,10,100,100);
            // I want to draw the arrow here but it is not working.
}
```

Answer (score 2):

I would actually do something along these lines:

Define an interface for drawable objects (to avoid confusion with the Android `Drawable` class, I've called it `Paintable`)

```
public interface Paintable {
    public void paint(Canvas canvas) {}
}
```

Make any classes that you need to draw in a custom manner, such as the arrow you suggested, implement the `Paintable` interface, and override `paint(Canvas canvas)` and handle your drawing operations there.

```
public class Arrow implements Paintable {
    //all sorts of cool shit here to define your arrow

    @Override
    public void paint(Canvas canvas) {
        //draw your arrow on the canvas here
    }
}
```

Maintain a list of `Paintable` objects in your custom `ImageView`, and simply call the `paint()` method for each object in the list. Yay for polymorphism!

```
public class Screen extends ImageView {
    List<Paintable> paintableObjects;

    public Screen(Context context) {
        super(context);
        paint.setColor(Color.BLACK);
        paint.setStyle(Style.STROKE);
        paintableObjects = new ArrayList<Paintable>();
    }

    public void addPaintable(Paintable p) {
        paintableObjects.add(p);
    }

    public void onDraw(Canvas canvas) {
        for(Paintable p : paintableObjects) {
            p.paint(canvas);
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I really don't see the reason of extending the `Canvas` and defining your own object, unless you need to have some special control over it.

Normally you extend `View` and do all the drawing stuff in the `onDraw()` method through the `Canvas` object, ex:

```
public void onDraw(Canvas canvas){

   canvas.drawLine(startPointX, startPointY, endPointX, endPointY, paint);

}
```

Answer (score 0):

this bit is wrong

```
public void onDraw(DrawObject drawObject){ ... }
```

onDarw is a frame work method so sice you change the method signature this method will not be called.

There is no need to subclass canvas - its not the right approach.

so in you Screen class - override the standard onDraw method:

```
public void onDraw(Canvas c){ 
   drawLine(startPointX, startPointY, endPointX, endPointY, paint);
}
```

to trigger the onDraw mthod programatically - call invalidate() on the Screen object.